# Highlight povray code with ConTeXt

Tags: context

How to highlight povray code with vim or ConTeXt.

I try with :

```tex
\usemodule[vim]

\definevimtyping [pov]  [syntax=povray]
```

I copy-paste povray code :

```tex
\startpov
 sphere { <0,0.2,0>, 1 texture{pigment{color Yellow filter .66 }
finish{phong .8}
}
   scale<1.5,1.5,1.5>  rotate<0,0,0>  translate<0,0.5,0>  
       }  // end of sphere ----------------------------------- 
\stoppov
```

Northing happened.

Comment: Could you provide a few more details, like a complete example and the output of the log file. What version of ConTeXt you are using, is write18 enabled, do you have vim installed on your system, and is there a vim syntax file for povray?

Comment: It seems that vim syntax for povray is called `pov`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vim syntax file for Pov-Ray is called `pov`. So, you need to change `syntax=povray` to `syntax=pov`. Here is a complete example:

```
\usemodule[vim]
\definevimtyping [pov]  [syntax=pov]

\starttext
\startpov
 sphere { <0,0.2,0>, 1 texture{pigment{color Yellow filter .66 }
finish{phong .8}
}
   scale<1.5,1.5,1.5>  rotate<0,0,0>  translate<0,0.5,0>  
       }  // end of sphere ----------------------------------- 
\stoppov
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]